# SKSpriteNode return null name

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Why the created name of a sprite isn't saved or even returned ?

I add several objects (SKSpriteNode) in the init of the Scene

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    NSArray *oxyObjects = [self.oxygens objectsNamed:@"oxy"];
    for (NSDictionary *enemyObj in oxyObjects) {
        SKSpriteNode *oxyNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"oxygen"];
        NSString *valeurX=enemyObj[@"x"];
        float x = [valeurX floatValue];
        NSString *valeurY=enemyObj[@"y"];
        float y = [valeurY floatValue];
        CGPoint oxyPosition = CGPointMake(x, y);
        oxyNode.position = oxyPosition;
        oxyNode.name = @"ballOxygen";
        NSLog(@"oxy %@",oxyNode);
        [self.map addChild:oxyNode];
    }
```

The log give me this with the correct name for the sprite

> oxy  name:'ballOxygen' texture:[ 'oxygen@2x.png' (24 x 24)] position:{454, 99} size:{12, 12} rotation:0.00

To check collision, I tried to use

```
    [[self children] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    SKNode *node = (SKNode *)obj;
    NSLog(@"obj : %@", obj);
```

Or this

```
NSArray *nodes = self.children;
for(SKNode * node in nodes){
    SKSpriteNode *obj = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
    NSLog(@"obj : %@", obj);
```

But It return always a null name

> obj :  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'Bird1@2x.png' (8 x 24)] position:{100, 100} size:{17, 12} rotation:0.00

Comment: Then you're most likely not looking at the same sprite/object. You can verify by comparing pointers, add this NSLog(@"id: %p", oxyNode) in both instances and compare pointer values - if they aren't identical they are different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess:

You are adding oxyNode to self.map but you are enumerating self.children where you probably should be enumerating self.map.children.

Try this:

```
[self.map.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    SKNode *node = (SKNode *)obj;
    NSLog(@"obj : %@ (%p)", obj, obj);
}];
```